# About a diophantine equation from group theory

Tags: nt.number-theory, gr.group-theory, prime-numbers, computational-number-theory

Is there any set of odd primes $\{p_1, p_2,..., p_k\}$ and natural numbers $a_1,..., a_k$ such that the following equation satisfied:
$${p_1^{2a_1+1}+1 \over p_1+1}\times ....\times {p_k^{2a_k+1}+1 \over p_k+1}={7\over 11} p_1^{2a_1} ... p_k^{2a_k}.$$
As we checked it seems that there is no solution for this equation, but we can not prove it. Any help or suggestions are very appreciated.

Comment: What does this have to do with group theory?

Comment: Each term in the left side is the summation of all elemnt orders of a cyclic $ p_I $-group.

Comment: Perhaps, BHZ, you could have put that information into the body of the question?

Comment: This is similar to odd perfect numbers.  There is a concept of fractional multi perfect numbers; Pace Nielsen or JoshuaZ might know some of that literature.  There are unlikely to be solutions as for most cases one of the left hand fractions is divisible by a large prime, and the presence of 7 implies that a small prime divides one of the exponents.  Since 11 must be one of the primes, you can look at large odd powers of 11 to get lower bounds on p_k. There are other OPN techniques to be used here.  Gerhard "Probably With Same OPN Results" Paseman, 2020.07.19.

Comment: I don't know if this should be called a Diophantine equation, since it is to be solved in prime numbers, rather than integers or rational numbers.

Comment: You asked for suggestions: a little help (but not much) may be provided by congruences (mod $8$). The left hand side is congruent to $\prod_{i} [ 1 +a_{i}(1-p_{i})]$ (mod $8$), and the right side is congruent  to $5$ (mod $8$).

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I try to use them and if I can solve it I will write it here.